# jquery - change style of element when hover another related with id and class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I would like to change color or any style (add class) of my first menu items when I hover on my second menu (submenu) elements (and remove class when not hover). These menus are related with id and class attribute.  I've got some problem with that.

My HTML:

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="mmenu">
<li class="mzr-drop panel-menu">
    <a class="menu-item menu-item-238" href="#">First</a>
    <a class="menu-item menu-item-243 active" href="#">Second</a>
    <a class="menu-item menu-item-246" href="#">Third</a>

    <div id="bg_menu_main" class="bg_menu">
            <div class="menu-header">
                <ul id="menu-main-nav-1" class="menu">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-238">
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-239" class="menu-item menu-item-239">Item</li>
                        <li id="menu-item-240" class="menu-item menu-item-240">Item</li>
                        <li id="menu-item-241" class="menu-item menu-item-241">Item</li>
                        <li id="menu-item-242" class="menu-item menu-item-242">Item</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-243">
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-244" class="menu-item menu-item-244">Item</li>
                        <li id="menu-item-245" class="menu-item menu-item-245">Item</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-246">
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-247" class="menu-item menu-item-247">Item</li>
                        <li id="menu-item-248" class="menu-item menu-item-248">Item</li>
                        <li id="menu-item-249" class="menu-item menu-item-249">Item</li>
                        <li id="menu-item-250" class="menu-item menu-item-250">Item</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

```
$('ul#menu-main-nav-1 li').hover(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#main-menu li.panel-menu').find('a.menu-item-'+id).addClass('hover');
});
```

And it is not working. What have I forgotten? Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Try to make a console.log of "id", it can't work because the var id is filled by the entire id name -> menu-item-239 , so when you do $('#main-menu li.panel-menu').find('a.menu-item-'+id).addClass('hover'); the .find() is filled in this way .find(a.menu-item-menu-item-239) ( 239 is an example of course ;) )

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your markup I guess you think that `id` gives an integer only, but the ids are preceded by `"menu-item-"`, so your selector would be `"menu-item-menu-item-xxx"`, try changing your code to this:

```
$('#main-menu li.panel-menu').find('a.' + id).addClass('hover');
```

Or even less code:

```
$('#main-menu li.panel-menu a.' + id).addClass('hover');
```

**Edit**: There appear to be no `<a>` tags at all, so this cant work. Finding a li:

```
$('#main-menu li.panel-menu.' + id).addClass('hover');
```

Comment: Ok. Here is [jffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/siojak/fCHmS/1/). But still not working.

Comment: Yes, but still nothing, I checked your code, and every in this thread. No ideas..

Comment: i mean there no a tags at all in your markup, how is this supposed to work then?

Comment: The 'a' tag is in my first menu (First, Second, Third items), so in my code .find i looking at these three and choose where  li id = a class. Still not working. In my jfiddle when I hover the below items my top menu not changing.

Comment: well for me it works, just add the proper markup or people wont be able to help you

Comment: Alex, I'm really greatful for your help and patience! I'm confused. Look in my updated **jfiddle** (http://jsfiddle.net/siojak/fCHmS/12/) It looks ok for me. 'a' tags exists, jquery seems to be ok. I changed addClass to css.color. I comment jquery which is working but for all top items (only for test), but still don't see my mistake for related id = class version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('ul#menu-main-nav-1 li').find('li[id^="menu-item-"]').hover(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#main-menu li.panel-menu').find('a.'+id).addClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`find('a.menu-item-'+id)` <<<<

if `id` is  `"menu-item-247"`

so it become `"a.menu-item-menu-item-247"`

Comment: please also try to suggesst a change in code than rather point out which part of the code seems to cause the bug